# Nested class takes more memory space?

Tags: java, memory-management, nested-class

I am little concerned about memory management, does having nested class is bad, does it take more memory when instance is created for main class, example:

***Case 1:***

```
class A 
{ 
   class B 
   {

   }

   int main() 
   {
       B b=new B();
   }
}
```

`A a=new A()` in other file, would also contain the class B structure and instance of B

***Case 2:***

```
class A 
{
   int main()
   {
       B b=new B();
   }
}

class B 
{
   //something
}
```

In this case in other file there will be instance of A, and in A instance of B

So, ***Case 1*** takes more memory or my thoughts are wrong? If I am wrong, please anyone explain me how this works.

Comment: What programming language are you talking about? Please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: @MattBall Java. For other languages is different?

Comment: Do not overcomplicate yourself. The difference would be trivial if any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

First: No, nested classes are not universally "bad." As is the case with almost everything else in programming - there is a time and a place for them.

Second: Yes - as you alluded to, a non-static inner class maintains an implicit reference to its outer class, so if an instance of the inner class is strongly referenced, then the outer instance is strongly referenced too. This means slightly more memory usage. BUT:

Third (and most importantly): The key word there is "slight." This consideration amounts to one of the "small effeciencies" Knuth is speaking of. **Do not let minor performance concerns drive the architecture of your program.** Focus on writing a clear, readable program with a clean, well-organized architecture: In many cases, the use of nested classes can create clearer organization - if yours is one of those cases, then use the nested class: The trade-off between a clearer architecture and such a minor increase in memory usage is one you want to take every time. If performance becomes an issue down the line, you'll be able to optimize then as long as your general architecture is solid. So focus on that architecture.

(Plus, programming is a lot more fun that way :) )

Comment: Thank you! I just read about Premature Optimization, I didn't knew that thing exist.